# How to get a tree structure ANLTR4

Tags: java, parsing, tree, antlr, antlr4

I need to parse config file in form like this

```
"agent 1"(
"ip"("192.67.4.1"),
"port"("12345"),
"neighbours"(
    "agent 2"(
        "ip"("192.67.4.2"),
        "port"("12345")),
    "agent 3"(
        "ip"("192.67.4.1"),
        "port"("12346"))),
"measurements"(
    "voltage"("4.2V"),
    "power"("7KW")))
```

What i got so far is grammar(mostly obtained just by trial and error method from few tutorials)

```
grammar Tree;

compileUnit
    :   group EOF
    ;

group
    :   (node '(' group ')' (',')? )*                # root
    |   node                                         # value
    ;
node
    : STRING                                         # label
    ;

STRING   :   '"'[ a-zA-Z0-9\.]+'"';
WS      :   [ \t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

and the result of it is tree like this in preview
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrMXr.png)

I already have functionality to add nodes to my tree in a form(other requirement):

> ADD "label 1" "label 2" ... "label n"

So the perfect outcome of parser would be String array like:

- "Agent 1" "ip" "192.67.4.1"
- "Agent 1" "port" "12345"
- "Agent 1" "neighbours" "agent 2" "ip" "192.67.4.2"
- "Agent 1" "neighbours" "agent 2" "port" "12345"
- And so on...

But I couldn't get further and implement my parser to obtain such String array. So my question is how to do it? I get that I need to extend something like Parser of BasicListener but couldn't manage this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

First, let's change the named alternative `root` to:

```antlr
group
    :   node '(' (group (',')?)+ ')'     # root
    |   node                             # value
    ;
```

This allows us to track the header (`node`) of every `group`. When I refer further to a *tree* what I mean is *config tree structure*. Then let's make two definitions:

- **path** - is a string of values collected from tree's root to tree's leaf (e.g. `"Agent 1" "neighbours" "agent 2" "ip" "192.67.4.2"`),
- **partial path** - is a path that doesn't end with tree's leaf (an unfinished **path**, e.g. `"Agent 1" "neighbours" "agent 2" "ip"`).

Now we will write a simple tree listener that will collect **paths**.

```java
public class TreeToArray extends TreeBaseListener {
    Stack<String> partialPath = new Stack<>();
    public List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void enterRoot(TreeParser.RootContext ctx) {
        if (partialPath.isEmpty()) {
            // We are in top-root, partial path consists of top-root's name
            partialPath.push(ctx.node().getText());
        } else {
            // We are in one of the sub-roots, partialPath.peek() returns a current partial path
            partialPath.push(partialPath.peek() + " " + ctx.node().getText());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void enterValue(TreeParser.ValueContext ctx) {
        paths.add(partialPath.peek() + " " + ctx.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void exitRoot(TreeParser.RootContext ctx) {
        partialPath.pop();
    }
}
```

The stack `partialPath` keeps information about currently built **partial path**. When we visist the main, first `root` (e.g. `"Agent 1"`) we don't have any **partial paths**, so we put onto the stack the `root`'s header. Otherwise we retrive a **partial path** and add to it root's header. When we stumble across `value` we are at the tree's leaf, we finished the **path**. We `pop()` the **partial path**, then we add to it `node` value. The result string (the full **path**) goes into the `paths` list.

Comment: Almost got it but in enterRoot calling getText() on ctx.node() gives me error cose ctx.node() returns List<NodeContext> and I'm not good enough to fix it myself.

Comment: @EugeneShymko: You need to regenerate classes from the Tree.g4 grammar! `root` rule alternative has with new grammar only one `NodeContext` not a list `List<NodeContext>` :)

Comment: Its fine now! Thanks! Is there some books/tutorials you can recommend? Started this only like an assignment but now it seems like really useful tool :)

Comment: @EugeneShymko: definetely two books by one of the ANTLRv4's authors Terence Parr ([_"The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference: Building Domain-Specific Languages"_](https://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) and [_"Language Implementation Patterns: Create Your Own Domain-Specific and General Programming Languages"_](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns)) also you should checkout [_ANTLRv4 online documentation_](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Comment: @EugeneShymko: you can also watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8p1voEiu8Q) by Terence Parr :)